# Rename files by regexp in command line

Tags: rename

I do a mistake when trying to move files from one location to another. Now all files are moved, but there is a `*` concatenated at the end of all names.

How do I remove all `*`s from end of file names in command line?

**Note:** I'm working with an embedded system, there is not any Internet connection. Please provide solutions with no need to install new stuff.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a command called (in an excess of originality) `rename`, that allows you to rename files using regular expressions.

In this case, you probably want to do:

```
rename 's/\*//' files...
```

Which will remove the first `*` character found in each filename.

You can use `rename -n` to list the renames that will be performed without actually doing them if you're worried about the regex not being correct.

Comment: This will replace every `*` anywhere in a file name (not only at the end). `s/\\*$//` or `'s/\*$//'` would probably work better.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu comes with the [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/prename.1.html) command which can rename files by regular expressions.

If all your files are located in the same folder, you can simply do the following:

```
rename s/\\*$// *
```

(`\\*` is an escaped `*`, `$` is the end of the file name. A match will be replaced with nothing.)

If all your files are in a directory structure, you can use find:

```
find / -exec rename s/\\*$// {} \;
```

Which executes `rename /\\*$//` on every file and directory on you system. Feel free to change the `/` to the folder in which the directory structure is located.