# Rename files in group

Tags: command-line, rename, scripts

I've folder and file structure like

```
Folder/1/fileNameOne.ext
Folder/2/fileNameTwo.ext
Folder/3/fileNameThree.ext
...
```

How can I rename the files such that the output becomes

```
Folder/1_fileNameOne.ext
Folder/2_fileNameTwo.ext
Folder/3_fileNameThree.ext
...
```

**How can this be achieved in linux shell?**

Comment: also asked on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15952463/7552)

Comment: Look for 'rename' command, that support regexp rename
 http://askubuntu.com/questions/175281/rename-files-by-regexp-in-command-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a bash script that does that:

***Note: This script does not work if any of the file names contain spaces.***

```
#! /bin/bash

# Only go through the directories in the current directory.
for dir in $(find ./ -type d)
do
    # Remove the first two characters. 
    # Initially, $dir = "./directory_name".
    # After this step, $dir = "directory_name".
    dir="${dir:2}"

    # Skip if $dir is empty. Only happens when $dir = "./" initially.
    if [ ! $dir ]
    then
        continue
    fi

    # Go through all the files in the directory.
    for file in $(ls -d $dir/*)
    do
        # Replace / with _
        # For example, if $file = "dir/filename", then $new_file = "dir_filename"
        # where $dir = dir
        new_file="${file/\//_}"

        # Move the file.
        mv $file $new_file
    done

    # Remove the directory.
    rm -rf $dir
done
```

- Copy-paste the script in a file.
- Make it executable using

```
chmod +x file_name
```

- Move the script to the destination directory. In your case this should be inside `Folder/`.
- Run the script using `./file_name`.