# Rename multiple files with same digits after decimal

Tags: bash, files, batch-rename

I have multiple files with names
vort-0.01.txt,
vort-0.02.txt,
...

vort-0.1.txt
...
vort-0.2.txt
... etc.

I want to rename each files with two decimal points i.e. I want to change the name of vort-0.1.txt to vort-0.10.txt and keep vort-0.01.txt as it is.

How can I do that in using bash script?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you want to rename files with regular expressions. See : https://askubuntu.com/questions/175281/rename-files-by-regexp-in-command-line AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809666/rename-files-using-regular-expression-in-linux

Comment: mmv is well suited for this kind of [renaming](https://askubuntu.com/a/1217686/986805)

Answer (score 2):

Using the perl-based `rename` command, then given

```
$ ls vort*.txt
vort-0.001.txt  vort-0.01.txt  vort-0.1.txt  vort-0.2.txt
```

then

```
rename -n 's/(\d+\.\d+)/sprintf "%.2f", $1/e' vort*.txt
```

will impose 2-digit precision everywhere, as

```
rename(vort-0.001.txt, vort-0.00.txt)
rename(vort-0.1.txt, vort-0.10.txt)
rename(vort-0.2.txt, vort-0.20.txt)
```

If you want to rename to a *minimum* precision i.e. only modify filenames that currently have single-digit precision, then

```
$ rename -n 's/(\d+\.\d)(?=\D)/sprintf "%.2f", $1/e' vort*.txt
rename(vort-0.1.txt, vort-0.10.txt)
rename(vort-0.2.txt, vort-0.20.txt)
```

Remove the `-n` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

---

To do the same thing using bash shell manipulations alone,

```
for f in vort-?.?.txt; do 
  base=${f%.txt}
  printf -v newname 'vort-%.2f.txt' "${base#vort-}"
  echo mv -- "$f" "$newname"
done
```

Here, remove the `echo` after testing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The rename command solve my purpose. However, when I use the bash shell manipulation using for loop it shows "bash: printf: ?.?: invalid number".